# TeXLive updated version mirror

Tags: texlive

How can I find the repository URL of the TeX Live version?

More precisely I have just downloaded Tex Live Utility for mac and when trying to list and update the packages with the URL https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet I received the following error

> Your TeX Live version is 2023, but your default repository URL appears to be for TeX Live 2022.  You need to choose an appropriate repository.

Comment: This is only a comment, since it will (probably) solve your problem, but not answer your question: wait a day or so, and try again. TeX Live 2023 was only released a day or so ago, and not all the mirrors have updated yet.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. I am using the mirror download.nus.edu.sg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that this is the same on most mirrors, and am happy to be corrected by people who actually know.

On my local mirror (in /pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/), there is a file called TEXLIVE_2022, which is 0 bytes long. At a guess, this will be changed to TEXLIVE_2023 when the mirror updates, so you can check that way if you know which mirror you use.

In any case (as I mentioned in the comment above), TL 2023 has just been released, so the mirrors may not have been updated yet, but should update over the next few days.